# How do I make method throw an exception if objects are not comparable?

Tags: java, exception, generics

Here you can see my main method where I want to sort two lists : people and animals with my sortAscending() method.
People have implemented compareTo method and therefore are comparable and work with this method.
Animal do not have implemented compareTo method.
What I want to do is throw some kind of an exception from my sortAscending method if objects are uncomparable. How can I do that ?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person person1 = new Person("Jonas", 36);
        Person person2 = new Person("Petras", 16);

        people.add(person1);
        people.add(person2);

        ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        Animal animal1 = new Animal("Cat", 3);
        Animal animal2 = new Animal("Dog", 1);

        animals.add(animal1);
        animals.add(animal2);

        System.out.println(Main.sortAscending(people));
        System.out.println(Main.sortAscending(animals));
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> ArrayList<T> sortAscending(
            final ArrayList<T> list) {
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }
}

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    final String name;
    final int age;

    public Person(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{name=%s, age=%d}", name, age);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Person person) {
        return this.age < person.age ? -1 : this.age == person.age ? 0 : 1;
    }
}


public class Animal {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Animal(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{name=%s, age=%d}", this.name, this.age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Collections.sort(list);` instead of that unnecessary `sortAscending` method.

Because of the method [signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) of `sort`, the call won't even compile with a list containing elements that don't implement `Comparable`.

But if you must throw an exception,

```
if(!list.isEmpty() && !(list.get(0) instanceof Comparable))
{
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("List cannot be sorted");
}
else {
   Collections.sort(list);
}
```

Comment: my task is actually to write a method that sorts an arraylist in ascending order and throws an exception if objects are not comparable. Is it even possible to make this code compile without try catch block in main method ?

Comment: I need to chat with your professor about such a poorly designed assignment that undermines the lesson of the value of compile-time checking with generics. Anyway, see my edit.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Bound mismatch: The generic method sortAscending(ArrayList<T>) of type Main is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Animal>). The inferred type Animal is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>the code still doesnt compile, giving me this error :

Comment: As I said, get rid of sortAscending and run the code (or something similar) above. Check if the first item is Comparable and call sort on the list if it is.

Comment: This check is not sufficient to determine that one object is comparable to the other. Suppose I put an `Integer` and a `String` into the list. Each element is `instanceof Comparable`, but sorting will fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

if(list.get(0) != null && !(list.get(0) instanceof Comparable))
{
   throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: This check is not sufficient to determine that one object is comparable to the other. Suppose I put an `Integer` and a `String` into the list. Each element is `instanceof Comparable`, but sorting will fail.

Comment: @newacct , i think that part is already being taken care by ArrayList<String> rather than just ArrayList